# I don't seem to be getting blob data in my message from my websocket host to my Angular 2 Observable

Tags: angular, angular2-observables

I'm trying to convert some html/javascript to Angular 2 but I don't seem to be getting blob data in my message from my websocket host to my Angular 2 Observable.

Messages from my websocket host seem to be sending text messages just fine but blob messages show as empty objects.

Here's some of my code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class WebSocketService {
  private websocket: any;
  public sendMessage(text:string){
    this.websocket.send(text);
  }
  public GetInstanceStatus(): Observable<any>{
    this.websocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/something");
    return Observable.fromEvent(this.websocket,'message').map(res=>res);
  }
  sendText(json: Object) {
    this.websocket.send(json);
  }
  sendBinary(bytes: any) {
    this.websocket.send(bytes);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(
    private wss: WebSocketService
  ){
    this.wss.GetInstanceStatus().subscribe((result) => {
      console.log("received: " + result);
      var foo = result.data;
      for(var name in foo) {
        console.log( name + "::" + foo[name] )
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blob data would need to be parsed differently. Angular's `Http` service returns a `ResponseData` object that has a `.blob()` method on it, but unfortunately no support for WebSockets yet :/

You would have to parse it the old-fashioned way, by using the `FileReader`:

```
public GetInstanceStatus(): Observable<any>{
var reader = new FileReader();
this.websocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/something");

return Observable.fromEvent(this.websocket,'message')
  .map((res) => {
   // logic here for determining if res is a blob based on headers
   // here is what you'd do for a blob though:
   reader.readAsArrayBuffer(res.body)
  });
}
```

The implementation of this is going to vary based on your payload. The `readAsArrayBuffer` method will parse the data as an array; this might not be what you need. Check out the MDN docs on `FileReader`  [here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader)

The main point is that you're going to want to do some mapping logic to see whether it should be parsed as a blob or not and return it that way.